# GPS Mathematics

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request, circles

I am a high school student doing the IB diploma. I decided to do my Math Internal Assessment exploring the mathematics behind GPS. I am not that good at physics and have to focus only on the mathematical part of GPS. Can you please suggest me some good problems I can discuss in my writing that include GPS?
All in all, I have explained the theory for 2D and 3D trilateration but I need some real life examples as well. Thank you!

Comment: Gilbert Strang's book Linear Algebra, Geodesy, and GPS is a good book on the math behind GPS.

Comment: An option is to write a description of the properties of [Gold sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code). There is some nice algebra of their properties explaining how we get can track the time separation to the distances to various satellites. With data on the timing differences at your fingertipes finding the position becomes a banal exercise in analytic geometry.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a problem I can solve for gold sequences?